# Rotate view around world origin with mouse

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible?
Numpad keys allow me to do radical rotations around world origin, I'd like to have more control with my mouse

Comment: If you do have a mouse, then just click and drag with the middle mouse button (the scroll button)

Comment: @TheKalaakaar I don't think that rotates around world origin

Comment: Neither do the numpad keys.Think of an imaginary dot in the middle of you screen(but in like 3d space) this is what you orbit around. For example move a cube away fromthe origin and now press the "." key to orbit around it. You will get the same result from the mouse as well as the numpad keys